# Multiple grep search/ignore patterns

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, grep

I usually use the following pipeline to grep for a particular search string and yet ignore certain other patterns:

```
grep -Ri 64 src/install/ | grep -v \.svn | grep -v "file"| grep -v "2\.5" | grep -v "2\.6"
```

Can this be achieved in a succinct manner? I am using GNU grep 2.5.3.

Comment: The usefulness of the answer also depends on which strings are likely to change.  If the only changing string is "64" why don't you create a function or shell script for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just pipe your unfiltered output into a single instance of grep and use an extended regexp to declare what you want to ignore:

```
grep -Ri 64 src/install/ | grep -v -E '(\.svn|file|2\.5|2\.6)'
```

**Edit:** To search multiple files maybe try

```
find ./src/install -type f -print |\
    grep -v -E '(\.svn|file|2\.5|2\.6)' | xargs grep -i 64
```

**Edit:** Ooh. I forgot to add the simple trick to stop a cringeable use of multiple grep instances, namely

```
ps -ef | grep something | grep -v grep
```

Replacing that with

```
ps -ef | grep "[s]omething"
```

removes the need of the second grep.

Comment: The parenthesizes must be quoted .. otherwise bash complains: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: There is one bug in your solution and the example in my question: the second grep will match the actual line *and* the filename that appears in the output of the first grep. This is good for ignoring `.svn` .. but not other patterns.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you're saying there but maybe try the update above

Comment: You might want to reverse the order of `grep -v` that removes filenames and the `xargs` so that `xargs` only gets the files you want to grep to begin with.

Comment: If the `grep -v .svn` was meant to keep out matches from SVN files, how about `find src/install -type f -name '*.svn' -o -print | xargs fgrep 64 | egrep -lv 'file|2\.[56]'`

Comment: It has been mentioned above in passing, but it bears repetition that `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-e` option to specify multiple patterns:

```
grep -Ri 64 src/install/ | grep -v -e '\.svn' -e file -e '2\.5' -e '2\.6'
```

You might also be interested in the `-F` flag, which indicates that patterns are fixed strings instead of regular expressions. Now you don't have to escape the dot:

```
grep -Ri 64 src/install/ | grep -vF -e .svn -e file -e 2.5 -e 2.6
```

I noticed you were grepping out ".svn". You probably want to skip any directories named ".svn" in your initial recursive grep. If I were you, I would do this instead:

```
grep -Ri 64 src/install/ --exclude-dir .svn | grep -vF -e file -e 2.5 -e 2.6
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use awk instead of grep

```
awk '/64/&&!/(\.svn|file|2\.[56])/' file
```

Comment: This succinctly prints lines from a single file, but fails to do the recursion from the first grep.  But it can fruitfully be used in combination with the suggested `find | xargs` solution.  Should also add printing of the file name before the match in order to fully emulate grep behaviour, though.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want to use [ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) which allow to exclude with perl regexp as well and avoid all the VC directories, great for grepping source code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; for purely Python source tree, I currently use `py.lookup` from http://pylib.org/

Answer (score 0):

The following script will remove all files except a list of files:

```
echo cleanup_all $@


if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
FILES=`find . -type f`
else
EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP="("
for EXCLUDED_FILE in $@
do
    EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP="$EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP./$EXCLUDED_FILE|"
done
# strip last char
EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP="${EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP%?}"
EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP="$EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP)"
echo exluded files expression :  $EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP

     FILES=`find . -type f | egrep -v $EXCLUDE_FILES_EXP`
fi

echo removing $FILES

for FILE in $FILES
do
    echo "cleanup: removing file $FILE"
    rm $FILE
done
```